# How do I call a stored procedure within a stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am converting a MS- Access database to MySQL and in Access you can call a query from within a query. How do I do that in MySQL using stored procedures?

I tried this, where YearCurrentPulledOut is another stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BigDitchCurrentYear`()
BEGIN
SELECT `BigDitchCurrentYearSub`.`BigDitchID`, `BigDitchCurrentYearSub`.`BeginDate`, `BigDitchCurrentYearSub`.`EndDate`, `BigDitchCurrentYearSub`.`Amount`
FROM `YearCurrentPulledOut` 
INNER JOIN `BigDitchCurrentYearSub` ON `YearCurrentPulledOut`.`YearPulledOut` = `BigDitchCurrentYearSub`.`YearNow`;
END
```

And get an error:
Error Code: 1146. Table 'gmwua_alpha.yearcurrentpulledout' doesn't exist

Comment: you call it with `CALL procedurename(arguments...)` just like the way yuo called `BigDitchCurrentYear`

Comment: If you're trying to join with the results of the SP, that's not possible.

Comment: What made you think that ? the documentation defines tableexpressionin the from clause as 'The name of the table or tables containing the data you want to retrieve.' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/select-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: Perhaps [views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html) or [subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) will better fit what you are trying to achieve?